# R: how to insert a number to an ordered vector

Tags: r

Can anybody tell me how to insert a number to an ordered vector.

Suppose my vector is `x <- c(4, 6, 9, 10, 13, 15, 19)`， and I want to insert `11` between `10` and `13`? Can you tell me how to find out that the inserted column and find out its position in the new vector?

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `order`, maybe you could do:

```
x <- c(4, 6, 9, 10, 13, 15, 19)
ins <- 11
point <- which(order(c(ins,x))==1)
point
#[1] 5

append(x, ins, point-1)
#[1]  4  6  9 10 11 13 15 19
```

An alternative that might be more direct is `?Position`:

```
point <- Position(function(v) v < ins, x, right=TRUE)
append(x, ins, after=point)
#[1]  4  6  9 10 11 13 15 19
```

Comment: or in short : append(x,ins,max(which(x<ins)))

Comment: I am surprised that I got an answer so fast! it's really helpful!

Comment: @HosseinVatani that fails when ins is less than every element in x

Answer (score 4):

To find the position where it will be inserted you can do

```
v <- c(4,6,9,10,13,15,19)
i <- 11

length(which(v <= i)) + 1
# [1] 5
```

To insert it, you can insert (concatenate) the new value directly, then sort the resulting vector and find the position of your new value

```
v <- sort(c(v, i))
which(v==i)
# [1] 5
```

Comment: Your answer is very helpful too! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

If your vector is already ordered, another way to achieve desired result is

```
x <- c(4, 6, 9, 10, 13, 15, 19)
i <- 11
x <- c(x[x < i], i, x[x >= i])
x
[1]  4  6  9 10 11 13 15 19
```

To find location you can do

```
sum(x < i) + 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is very helpful too

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
> b <- c(x[1:4], 11, x[5:7])
[1]  4  6  9 10 11 13 15 19
```

to insert them before 10 and 13

And then you can do

```
> which(x==11)
[1] 5
```

To find the location of 11

Comment: while this is 'strictly' correct for this specific example, it's not generalisable

Comment: No problem. I am still learning the best way to answer questions on SO. Just joined recently. Thanks @tospig for the tip!

Comment: @YuanTang I find it best to assume the question asked is just a smaller example of a much bigger problem, and so the answer will need to scale up.

Comment: Haha, it's really nice of you :)  I am new here too. Hope to see you again!